# c# Doing a sum of results of a search in a array

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, sum

Ok so here's my problem. I have a vehicle constructor with several specs, and a class array that registers vehicles.

Within my form i wish to let the user search within that array for a specific value (in this case he shall input the type of vehicle and the year of the purchase, thus searching the array for them, and upon finding correspondents, he must then pick their price of acquisition and selling) and it shall return the sum of the profit.

Or in a simpler way: Profit = price of selling - price of acquisition.

The code I have thus far shows the profit individually and then the sum of the profits, how do I get just the latter?

```
int i;
        bool found = false;
        double lucro = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < viaturas.NumElementos; i++)
            if (viaturas.get(i).CVTipoVeículo == Int32.Parse(cbtipoveiculo.Text))
            {
                if (viaturas.get(i).CVDataVenda.Year == Int32.Parse(tbanopesquisa.Text))
                {
                    double a = viaturas.get(i).CVPreçoVenda;
                    double b = viaturas.get(i).CVPreçoAquisição;
                    lucro += a - b;
                    found = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("O total de lucro das vendas em   " + viaturas.get(i).CVDataVenda.Year + "   foi de:   " + lucro + "€", "Lucro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                }
            }
        if (found == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Conjunto de viaturas não existente!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            LimpaCampos();
        }
```

Comment: Just declare another variable called _double Total = 0;_ then inside the loop write _Total += lucro;_ at the end you will have the total

Comment: You should use the System.Linq library extensions for achieve this. It's clearest and quick enough. Seems like you aren't familiar with C#, am I right?

Comment: @Steve I did it like this, and I still get more that one message of individual profits.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza say programming in general instead! but how would I do it with Linq?

Comment: It would be like `viaturas.Where(v => v.CVTipoVeículo == Convert.ToInt32(cbtipoveiculo.Text)).Sum(i => i.CVPreçoVenda - i.CVPreçoAquisição)` and you wouldn't need of the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value where you have all the profit summed then change your code to the following

```
    int i;
    bool found = false;
    double lucro = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < viaturas.NumElementos; i++)
        if (viaturas.get(i).CVTipoVeículo == Int32.Parse(cbtipoveiculo.Text))
        {
            if (viaturas.get(i).CVDataVenda.Year == Int32.Parse(tbanopesquisa.Text))
            {
                double a = viaturas.get(i).CVPreçoVenda;
                double b = viaturas.get(i).CVPreçoAquisição;
                lucro += a - b; // Add it instead of overwriting

                found = true;
                //falta-me pô-lo a somar todos os lucros.

            }
        }
// Show a MessageBox here with a text (Sorry, I don't speak your language) that outputs your 'lucro' variable
```

If this is not what you meant, then I don't know how you can put all the profit into one value

Comment: That actually sort of works. but now i get two messageboxes, the first shows A profit and the second shows the sum of the profits.
(PS sorry for the language :/)

Comment: You have to remove the first MesageBox within the for statement and only leave the last one that shows the sum.